# How to sum values by object name?

Tags: sql, database

I have order-table like this;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Npaw.png

Name of product and amount bought.

How do i list the names of products and count their total amount?
In jupyter notebook it`s easy , create new int and add them if curentname == temp name then total = total + temp and so on.
but in sql i do not have idea how to realize it.

Comment: I would suggest you attach the image or a sample of the data directly inside the question and make it more clear.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT PRODUCT_NAME ,SUM(AMOUNT) FROM ORDERS GROUP BY PRODUCT_NAME;